# subcaption width is not registered

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to use subcaption in order to show two aligned images. This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{caption}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{Figures/fig.png}
          \caption{1a}
          \label{fig:sfig1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{Figures/fig.png}
          \caption{1b}
          \label{fig:sfig2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{plots of....}
        \label{fig:fig}
      \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Everything works except one thing: The width of the subfigures are not registered. Whenever I compile it, the 0.4 appears on the document instead of being registered as a factor. This is the result:

[image]

I have been looking for some answers online for the past hour and everyone suggests the same lines of code as I have. Is there something I am missing out?

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please make yor code snipped compilable, i.e. add `\documentclass{...}` and used package.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Perhaps you have an outdated distribution. Update it and try again by following the instructions listed in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: I can reproduce the output if I replace `subcaption` with `subfigure` and ignore the compilation errors. Is there a `\usepackage{subfigure}` lurking in your code somewhere.

Comment: @Werner I am using the ShareLatex website. I am pretty sure the version is up to date.

Comment: @ShEsKo: Are you using the (obsolete) `subfigure` package?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. was right. There was effectively a \usepackage{subfigure}. It was placed in a file I had not checked. Thanks everyone for the help!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a wrongly loaded conflicting package

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**. It is not clear to me, what is you thing that is wrong with your code. If you like to have captions and sub captions centered belong images, you need to add `\centering` as you can see in code below. Otherwise, "scaling" works as expected. To see this, I add rule in the first sub figure width length of `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering%<---
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering%<---
    \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{1a}
    \label{fig:sfig1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
  \centering%<---
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{1b}
    \label{fig:sfig2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{plots of....}
  \label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

In code I add package`showframe` that the position of figure on the page is better seen. Is this what you looking for? I was not able to reproduce your image width your code.

Comment: Hi Zarko, Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the behaviour is the same as previously. The proportion values of \textwidth are still shown on the figure meaning that they are not having any effect on the sizing of the subfigures

Comment: @ShEsKo, see edit of my answer.